# Yii passing parameters to widget

Tags: yii, yii-components

Sorry if I am using wrong keyword. Might be I did not get sufficient information due to wrong keyword.

we create widget in Yii by this way:

```
class streamList extends CWidget {
  //do some stuff
}
```

Also, we use this widget anywhere as

```
$this->widget("application.components.widget.streamList");
```

How can we write the widget in such a way that it accepts parameter(s) as

```
$this->widget("application.components.widget.streamList",array('title'=>'Posts');
```

I googled but did not solve. Please help, thank in advance.

**Edit log:**
Also, how can we define default parameter value to 'titile'? I tried `public $title = Shk::getTitle()`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
class StreamList extends CWidget {
    //do some stuff
    public $title;
}
```

Any attributes can be initialized with default values and overwritten by

```
$this->widget("application.components.widget.StreamList",array('title'=>'Posts',.....)
```

**EDIT**

You can't initialize class attributes with functions. An explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633024/428543). An option is to check whether `$title` is set and if not set it to `Shk::getTitle()` in the `init()` method like

```
public function init(){
    ....
    if(!isset($this->title) || !$this->title)
        $this->title=Shk::getTitle();
    ....
}
```

P.S for consistency it's better to Capitalize your class names.

Comment: Is the file `Shk` autoloaded?

Comment: The error isn't with the class it's with the initialization. I've edited the answer because of this.