# Syntax error when accessing static array with in class

Tags: php

```
public static $config = array(
    'base_url' => '',
    'environment' => '',
    'database' => array(
        'dbdriver' => '',
        'dbhost'   => '',
        'dbname'   => '',
        'dbuser'   => '',
        'dbpass'   => ''
    ),
```

I want to access the `base_url` key and assign it to a new static property $app but it is giving me syntax error of unexpected `[`

```
public static $app_path = self::config['base_url']; //unexpected [ error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access variable so you have to add `$`.

```
self::$config['base_url']
```

Read some more about that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Unfortunately you can't assign any variable (even static) to other static property as you can see in linked manual page.

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

Comment: @RaheelKhan oh, I missed that you want to assign that to another static property, not just use. Check edited answer.

Comment: Oh damn, I would probably need to use getters for this :(

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual:

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

[Right here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

And before you think this is a severe limitation, let me tell you why this is a blessed relief:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $evil = array('bar' => 123);
    public static $check = self::$evil['bar'];
}
Foo::$check;//all is well
```

But then, when you introduce late static binding (something we all love):

```
class Foo
{
    public static $evil = array('bar' => 123);
    public static $check = static::$evil['bar'];
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public static $evil = 123;
}
Bar::$check;//OOOPS
```

TL;TR: statics are something like super-globals: you can initialize them with a constant expression, but they can't require state to be initialized, that would be inception madness

Comment: So by your example i think it is same case for non static properties ? We will have same problem.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Of course, what's more: with non-static properties, you can't initialize/declare them using `public $foo = $this->bar;` because `$this` doesn't exist before the instance is created. You'll have to use the constructor to initialize the properties using `$this`

Answer (score 1):

The way you've initilized your (static) properties, is not yet implemented in PHP
You can check this thread's explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633024/4098311

However, this is how i'm doing in my projects :

```
<?php
class YourClass {
    public static $config       = NULL;
    public static $app_path     = NULL;
    public static $_INITIALIZED = FALSE;

    public static init() {
        if(!self::$_INITIALIZED) {
            self::$config = array(
                                'base_url' => '',
                                'environment' => '',
                                'database' => array(
                                    'dbdriver' => '',
                                    'dbhost'   => '',
                                    'dbname'   => '',
                                    'dbuser'   => '',
                                    'dbpass'   => ''
                                ));
            self::$app_path = self::config['base_url'];
            self::$_INITIALIZED = TRUE;
        }
    }
    // ....
    // Your Stuf ...
    // ....
}
YourClass::init();
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution.