# php function inside array

Tags: php, arrays, function, compiler-errors

I try to store a function inside an array but it keeps giving me this **error**:

> unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)

I looked around on internet but they mostly say that I should be using php version 5.3 and above, while I am using `5.6.21`.

Here is my array:

```
       static $Events = array(
            'View Page' => array(
                'properties' => array(
                    'previous_event',
                    'number_view_page',
                ),
                'trigger' => function($foo){
                    return $foo;
                },
            ),
        );
```

If anyone knows what the problem is and how to solve it, please help me :)

Comment: It doesn't work because it is not implemeneted in php. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633024/3595565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` values need to be initialised with static/*constant* expressions. Sadly, anonymous functions aren't "constant" enough to count. Later PHP versions allow some limited expressions like `2 + 4` (because the result is always constant), but nothing more than that. Function declarations are too complex to handle in a `static` context (you can add a function to the array *afterwards* at any time, you just can't *initialise* it that way*).

<sub>* The reason for this restriction is that `static` declarations are handled at a different parsing phase than runtime code, and that parsing phase cannot handle anything but primitive values.</sub>

Comment: I changed the event handling but still thank you! You explained it very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Try again with this (you have 2 ,, too much at the end of the code and please remove the static)

EDIT: adding function so you can use the array from other class.

```
function $events_func()
{
    $events = array(
        'View Page' => array(
            'properties' => array(
                'previous_event',
                'number_view_page',
            ),
            'trigger' => function($foo){
                return $foo;
            }
        )
    );
return $events;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt solve anything, and I am using static because this is inside a helper class so it can be used in any controller function

Comment: you should create a function method inside your helper class that will return this array.

then you can use it in your controller function.